# List all Processes & Threads under processes from Linux core dump using gdb

Tags: linux, operating-system, gdb, cgdb

I am developing a scripting tool for gdb/linux core dump, where if I point script to core bump , it lists all stack traces of all threads under process i.e, what I am trying to achieve  is pretty much gdb equivalent of windbg's !process 0 which dumps all the processes and threads with stack from dump.

Is there gdb equivalent of !process 0 ?

if Not

Whats the gdb command to list all the processes and list all threads under processes in gdb from core dump ?

This would enable me to write a script to loop over all pid's and tid's and get an backtrace which could be logged to an file?

Also suggestions on scripting language for this such as perl/python, the better one is welcome.

Thanks
Ganesh

Answer (score 3):

This will give you back-traces of all the threads with all locals at all frames:

`(gdb) thread apply all bt full`

I don't think single core file covers more then one process. Take a look at [GDB documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) for your scripting options.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `thread apply all bt`, you'll do well to use Python interpreter that is [built *into*](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html) recent GDB versions, rather than try to parse GDB textual output.

Nikolai is correct in that a UNIX core file only covers one process (the one that crashed or was killed).

Comment: Hi , I was looking for executing gdb commands from python , like $var=`bt` will contain the output in $ var. This seems to deal with executing python script inside gdb.